# Changing the ContentControl binding results in a null DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn

Perhaps one of you could enlighten me on the following problem.
I'm using a list box as a way to navigate between 2 viewmodels.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFApp.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">

  <Grid Background="White">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ListBox Grid.Column="0" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] 
= [Action onViewSelectionChange($this.SelectedItem.Text)]">
        <TextBlock Text="FirstView"/>
        <TextBlock Text="SecondView"/>
     </ListBox>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding MyViewModel}"/>
  </Grid>
```

```
namespace MyWPFApp
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase, IShell
   {
      private object _vm;

      public object MyViewModel
      {
         get { return _vm; }
         set { _vm = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyViewModel); }
      }

      public FirstViewModel vm1;
      public SecondViewModel vm2;



      public ShellViewModel()
      {
         vm1 = new FirstViewModel();
         vm2 = new SecondViewModel();
         MyViewModel = vm1;

      }

      public void onViewSelectionChange(string str)
      {

         switch (str)
         {
            case "FirstView":
               MyViewModel = vm1;
               break;
            case "SecondView":
               MyViewModel = vm2;
               break;
            default:
               break;

         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've create 2 datatemplates to associate the viewmodel with its view

```
<Application x:Class="MyWPFApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-MyWPFApp">
  <Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
           <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstViewModel}">
        <Grid>
           <local:FirstView></local:FirstView>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondViewModel}">
        <Grid>
           <local:SecondView></local:SecondView>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
  </Application>
```

FirstView actually has controls which have bindings to properties in FirstViewModel

```
   <UserControl x:Class="MyWPFApp.FirstView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFApp"
            xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid Background="Aquamarine">
     <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action OnLBSelectionChanged($source)]">
        <ListBoxItem>apple</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>orange</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>pear</ListBoxItem>
     </ListBox>
  </Grid>
```

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWPFApp
{
   public class FirstViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {

      private int _selectedindex;

      public int SelectedIndex
      {
         get { return _selectedindex; }
         set { _selectedindex = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedIndex); }
      }


      private string _selecteditem;

      public string SelectedItem
      {
         get { return _selecteditem; }
         set { _selecteditem = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem); }
      }



      public FirstViewModel()
      {
      }


      public void OnLBSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.ListBox lb)
      {
         if(lb.DataContext == null)
         {
            Debug.WriteLine("The DataContext is null");
         }

      }

   }
}
```

The SecondView contains no controls.

When the ShellView list box selection changes from FirstView to SecondView, I've noticed that the FirstView ListBox DataContext becomes null.

```
  public void OnLBSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.ListBox lb)
  {
     if(lb.DataContext == null)
     {
        Debug.WriteLine("The DataContext is null");
     }

  }
```

I would prefer not to have to handle selection changes looking for a null DataContext. Instead, I'd like to know what's actually happening. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is that the `DataContext` for `FirstView` is implicitly wired up by WPF when the `ContentControl`'s `Content` property is set to the `FirstViewModel` via data binding.

Once the binding changes to be `SecondViewModel` the `FirstViewModel` goes out of scope and thus WPF cleans up after itself, removing `FirstViewModel`, `FirstView`, and its implicit `DataContext` binding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My solution to this issue was to respond to a selection change event (which happens when the DataContext becomes null) and check for a null DataContext. Is there a way to prevent the DataContext from becoming null? e.g. changing visibility of ContentControl as opposed  to switching between ViewModels

Comment: You need to change how your're doing things if you want both views and view models to stay alive. You can't accomplish what you want with your current code. I would recommend just newing up your two views and view models and wire up their data context in code. Then switch between them.

Comment: Caliburn Micro has a way to do this using `Conductor.Collection.OneActive` or `.AllActive` depending on your use case. Have you looked at the lifecycle events for these types in the framework?